# OracleDbConsole and OracleJobScheduler

Tags: oracle

OracleDbConsole and OracleJobScheduler services in Oracle - What tasks they performing?

Answer (score 1):

DB Console is for Enterprise Manager and the JobScheduler will be for the Job Scheduler (batch jobs run through DBMS_JOB and DBMS_SCHEDULER, which may include your stats gathering)